# Having Issues using Esri ArcGIS API for JavaScript in Lightning Web Component (require is not defined at eval)

Tags: requirejs, salesforce-lightning, arcgis-js-api, lwc

I'm trying to implement Esri ArcGIS JS in Lightning Web Component. While using ArcGIS JS, the sample code uses require function to load modules. In order to do that I'm trying to use require.js. I downloaded it from [here (Require.js)](https://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#requirejs). And then uploaded to my sandbox as static resource. I'm trying to use that static resource in my Lightning Web Component. I also added the script tag for the ArcGIS Javascript API in my Experience Cloud site's header as

```
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.24"></script>
```

Lightning Web Component:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import requireJS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/requireJS';

export default class TestMap extends LightningElement {
    renderedCallback() {
        loadScript(this, requireJS).then(() => {
            console.log('requireJS loaded');
            require([
                "esri/geometry/Extent"
            ], (
                Extent
            ) => {
                var initExtent = new Extent({
                    xmin: -15884312,
                    ymin: 1634835,
                    xmax: -6278767,
                    ymax: 7505198,
                    spatialReference: 102100
                });
            });
        }).catch(exception => {
            console.log(exception);
        });
    }
}
```

My problem right now, eventhough I can see in the Network tab that the require.js is loaded from static resource, require function cannot be found.

[Exception message catched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDLhn.png)

I'm not sure where is the issue since this is how I loaded my all javascript files before.

I was expecting to see the the require function is working after the require.js script loaded from Static Resource.

Answer (score 0):

This one is a bit tricky, I will try to guide you as much as I can.

First, don't put the script tag in your website header. This is a last chance solution, we'll keep it if nothing else work.

Second, requireJS is not compatible with LWC (or Locker Service to be precise). So you can forget it. `loadScript` is in someways similar.

Now the solution, usually I download the whole from a CDN and host it as a static resource. Then you can load it via `loadScript` and use it as per [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library).

In case the library is really small, it could be created as a LWC and then be imported but usually libraries are too heavy regarding Salesforce limit.

Looking at the library, it seems that they do not provide any compiled full version (which is probably huge). In this case I would recommend to make a custom build locally containing only the necessary pieces of code and then uploading as a static resource. Unfortunately I can't help on this part as I still didn't do it myself yet.

Feel free to comment and I will improve my answer is it's unclear.